# How to convert a JSON requestBody of the RestRequest to a Map of Strings?

Tags: apex, webservices, apexrest

A type of the body is JSON Blob in a form of:

`{"key1":"val1";"key2":"val2"}`

I wanted to convert it into a `Map<String, String>`. Do I have to manually deserialize it or there's a class which can handle that?

Comment: You can convert a Blob to a String. What is exactly your Blob? Does it contain json or xml?

Comment: I made my question more precise

Comment: It would really help us if you include all or relevant part of your response by editing your question.

Comment: Does it matter actually? Is just a JSON Blob. It looks like '{"key1":"val1";"key2":"val2"}' and I wanted to convert it into Map<String,String>. What exactly would you like me to provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me google that for you...

[https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=salesforce+json+deserialize](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=salesforce%20json%20deserialize)

The class is called JSON, and the method is:

```
public static Object deserializeUntyped(String jsonString)
```

So you use it as:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = (Map<String, object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
```

Comment: @Aiden: Shouldn't it be `Map<String, Object> myMap = (Map<String, object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Working code for you,

```
  String jsonInput =  '{\n'+ 

 ' "key1":"val1",\n'+

 '"key2":"val2"\n' +  '}';

   Map<String, Object> m = 
  (Map<String, Object>)
  JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);

  System.debug('jsonInput '+m.get('key1'));
```