# APEX: Insert values out of a JSON list into an object

Tags: apex, json

Below is the json that returns a callout and I would like to insert just the advisoryModel value into a field called PropuestaID from an object called Test.

With the code below, I managed to insert the entire data set into 1 fieldrecord. So just be able to select individual values from the json. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the data set:

```
[
    {
        "AdvisoryModel": "",
        "AdvisoryModelName": "",
        "AnalysisDate": "2017-09-01",
        "AssetClassDistrib": [
            {
                "Code": "5917",
                "Name": "Equities - Emerging Markets",
                "Value": 278.79749999999956,
                "Weight": 0.284105297215223
            },
            {
                "Code": "5911",
                "Name": "Equities - USA",
                "Value": 211.79749999999956,
                "Weight": 0.224105297215223
            }
        ],
        "AssetTypeDistrib": [
            {
                "Code": "8",
                "Name": "ETFs",
                "Value": 721.69750000000033,
                "Weight": 0.735437307497319
            },
            {
                "Code": "98",
                "Name": "ETFs",
                "Value": 721.69750000000033,
                "Weight": 0.735437307497319
            }
          ],
        "BenchmarkId": "16wUCvxf2IlH6LTDtskWKw==",
        "BenchmarkName": "",
        "Code": "MqzY3apIzI+7gLwtH81sg+5si1fQbB8XEuLscw2KLFw=",
        "CostValue": 981.3175,
        "Currency": "GBP",
        "CurrencyDistrib": [
            {
                "Code": "GBP",
                "Name": "GBP",
                "Value": 824.91750000000036,
                "Weight": 0.840622428520841
            }
        ],
        "InitialDate": "2016-11-09",
        "InOutflows": 0,
        "IsOpenPortfolio": false,
        "ModelPortfolioId": "16wUCvxf2IlH6LTDtskWKw==",
        "ModelPortfolioName": "",
        "Name": "All Jaime",
        "Nature": "Agreggated",
        "Performance1M": 0.0155937904269082,
        "Performance1W": -0.00370064850184649,
        "Performance1Y": null,
        "Performance1YOpen": 0.174732685075806,
        "Performance3M": 0.0100169290351478,
        "Performance3Y": null,
        "Performance5Y": null,
        "PerformanceStartDate": -0.00845315378943068,
        "PerformanceStartDateAnualized": -0.010413360304749042,
        "PerformanceYTD": -0.00798690763601953,
        "PortfolioCode": "24497@252",
        "PortfolioId": "K4dqbPaHvD3gu6jUXq7EjQ==",
        "PortfolioNature": "A",
        "ProfileId": 0,
        "ProfileName": "Without profile",
        "ProfitLoss": -18.6825,
        "ProfitLossPercent": -0.00845315378943068,
        "RatioSharpe": 2.1502607927577819,
        "RiskLevel": "Dynamic",
        "UnrealizedProfitLoss": -45.1225,
        "UnrealizedProfitLossPercent": -0.313,
        "TrendStrength": 0.00496941002014014,
        "Type": "Real",
        "UserId": "O1Zi/pdqdc2nt/ifOfzQPQ==",
        "Valuation": 981.3175,
        "ValuationStartDate": 1000,
        "Var1Y95": -0.126305977228028,
        "Volatility": 0.0812611594204373
    }
]
```

I have this code so far:

```
List<Object> results = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
   
for (Object agency: results) {
    System.debug((Map<String, Object>)agency); 
    Test__c ani = new Test__c();
    ani.PropuestaID__c=String.valueOf(agency);
    insert ani;
    System.debug('ani'+ani);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a JSON requestBody of the RestRequest to a Map of Strings?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203357/how-to-convert-a-json-requestbody-of-the-restrequest-to-a-map-of-strings)

Comment: Thank you, I went throug h the post although it is not clear to me. Sorry Im quite new to APEX coding. Would you know the code that Im missing in my example?

Comment: If it's not clear to you, I would recommend getting familiar with Apex Trails on Trailhead. Your problem is about basic/lower-intermediate concepts of web development.